# loop over a vector as to apply it to a function to perform webscraping

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping, nodes

I have a vector with two character list elements that I would like to apply through a loop to complete the necessary information on a URL from which I would like to web-scrape a specific node and obtain two lists  each with three sub-lists.

For a single URL I will do the following obtaining the desired output structure

```
library(rvest)
H1<- "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g1063979-d1756170-Reviews-La_Trobada_Hotel_Boutique-Ripoll_Province_of_Girona_Catalonia.html"
page0_url<-read_html (H1)
groupNodes <- html_nodes(page0_url,"._1nAmDotd") # get all nodes under the same heading     
outputlist <-lapply ( groupNodes , function(node) { 
results <- node %>% html_nodes("div") %>% html_text()
Hotel_Amenities <- outputlist[[1]][-9];
Room_Features <- outputlist [[2]] [-9];  
Room_Types <- outputlist[[3]]
Hotel_Amenities <- as.matrix(Hotel_Amenities)
Room_Features <- as.matrix(Room_Features)
})
print (Hotel_Amenities)
print (Room_Features)
print (Room_Types)
```

Attempting to run the same function for two URLs sequentially

```
library(rvest)
country <- data.frame ("d1447619-Reviews-Solana_del_Ter- 
Ripoll","d2219428-Reviews-La_Sequia_Molinar-Campdevanol")
for (i in country)
fun <- function (node) {
html_nodes ( read_html ( paste 
("https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Hotel_Review-g1063979- 
",i,"_Province_of_Girona_Catalonia.html", sep="" )) ,"._1nAmDotd")%>% 
html_nodes("div") %>% html_text()
}
lapply(country, fun)


# Produces two lists however the lists are the same list twice
```

I have tried more combinations. All either yield and error or at most obtain the result of only one of the two URLs and in a text string format.  Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: In your first attempt at a loop, you overwrite `outputlist` each time the loop is executed.  In your second, you reference the return value from `lapply` within the anonymous function on which `lapply` operates.

Comment: Your first code chunk does not work. `H1` link should be in quotes. After correcting that if we run `lapply`, it returns `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'outputlist' not found`

Comment: Thank you for your comments and for pointing out the correction, Upon correcting the first expresion does work. In regard to the second appears as there is an error accesing the website which produces the second error.                                                   
Error in open. (x, "rb") : HTTP error 400.
> print(outputlist)
Error in print(outputlist) : object 'outputlist' not found